# OR condition in Regex

Tags: regex

Let's say I have

```
1 ABC Street
1 A ABC Street
```

With `\d`, it matches ***1*** (what I expect), with `\d \w`, it matches ***1 A*** (expected). When I combine the patterns together `\d|\d \w`, it matches only the first one but ignores the second one.

My question is how to use "or" condition correctly in this particular case?

PS: The condition is wrapping the number only when there is no single letter after that, otherwise wrap the number and the single letter.

Example: ***1 ABC Street*** match number 1 only, but when ***1 A ABC Street*** wrap the ***1 A***

Comment: You don't necessarily have to use `|`, for example: `\d( \w)?`

Comment: \d( \w)? must solve your puzzle.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Try

```
\d \w |\d
```

or add a positive lookahead if you don't want to include the trailing space in the match

```
\d \w(?= )|\d
```

When you have two alternatives where one is an extension of the other, put the longer one first, otherwise it will have no opportunity to be matched.

Answer (score 56):

A classic "or" would be `|`. For example, `ab|de` would match either side of the expression.

However, for something like your case you might want to use the `?` quantifier, which will match the previous expression exactly 0 or 1 times (1 times preferred; i.e. it's a "greedy" match). Another (probably more relyable) alternative would be using a custom character group:

```
\d+\s+[A-Z\s]+\s+[A-Z][A-Za-z]+
```

This pattern will match:

- `\d+`: One or more numbers.
- `\s+`: One or more whitespaces.
- `[A-Z\s]+`: One or more uppercase characters or space characters
- `\s+`: One or more whitespaces.
- `[A-Z][A-Za-z\s]+`: An uppercase character followed by at least one more character (uppercase or lowercase) or whitespaces.

---

If you'd like a more static check, e.g. indeed only match `ABC` and `A ABC`, then you can combine a (non-matching) group and define the alternatives inside (to limit the scope):

```
\d (?:ABC|A ABC) Street
```

Or another alternative using a quantifier:

```
\d (?:A )?ABC Street
```

Comment: This seems a bit silly `\s+[A-Z\s]+\s+` - why do you need to match white space in three separate places? Surely either `[A-Z\s]+` or `\s+[A-Z]+\s+` make more sense...

Comment: Hm, yeah, thinking about it, it's a bit overkill after I removed the "first or last have to be letter" requirements. :) Editing... or not. It is still useful, because that way I force leading/trailing whitespaces, while allowing the brackets to match multiple words.

Comment: Surely that's a case for lookaround?

Answer (score 20):

I think what you need might be simply:

```
\d( \w)?
```

Note that your regex would have worked too if it was written as `\d \w|\d` instead of `\d|\d \w`.

This is because in your case, once the regex matches the first option, `\d`, it ceases to search for a new match, so to speak.