# Search for files & file names using silver searcher

Tags: command-line, terminal, grep, command-line-interface, ack

Using Silver Searcher, how can I search for:

1. (non-binary) files with a word or pattern **AND**
2. all *filenames*, with a word or pattern including filenames of binary files.

Other preferences: would like to have case insensitive search and search through dotfiles.

---

Tried to alias using this without much luck:

`alias search="ag -g $1 --smart-case --hidden && ag --smart-case --hidden $1"`

Comment: If you're using that alias in bash, you should note that [bash aliases don't take parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7131670/1743811).

Answer (score 60):

According to the man page of `ag`

```
   -G --file-search-regex PATTERN
          Only search files whose names match PATTERN.
```

You can use the `-G` option to perform searches on files matching a pattern.

So, to answer your question:

```
root@apache107:~/rpm-4.12.0.1# ag -G cpio.c size
rpm2cpio.c
21:    off_t payload_size;
73:    /* Retrieve payload size and compression type. */
76:     payload_size = headerGetNumber(h, RPMTAG_LONGARCHIVESIZE);
```

the above command searches for the word `size` in all files that matches the pattern `cpio.c`

Reference:
man page of `ag` version 0.28.0

### Note 1:

If you are looking for a string in certain file types, say all C sources code, there is an [undocumented feature](https://www.reddit.com/r/commandline/comments/3wwyvh/ag_vs_grep/cxztarq/) in `ag` to help you quickly restrict searches to certain file types.

The commands below both look for `foo` in all php files:

```bash
find . -name \*.php -exec grep foo {}
ag --php foo
```

While `find + grep` looks for all `.php` files, the `--php` switch in the `ag` command actually looks for the following file extensions:

```
.php  .phpt  .php3  .php4  .php5  .phtml
```

You can use `--cpp` for C++ source files, `--hh` for `.h` files, `--js` for JavaScript etc etc.  A full list can be found [here](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/blob/850e2b3887f0daa873fe2098f3f215b2c36000e1/tests/list_file_types.t)

### Note 2:

Keep in mind that when using language specific flags such as `--php` alongside the `--file-search-regex` option, then the `--file-search-regex` appears to be ignored at least per this example below

```
$ mkdir ag-test
$ cd ag-test
$ echo hello > blah.php
$ echo hello > mmkay.php
$ echo hello > special_something.txt
$ echo hello > special_also.php
$ echo nothing > nope.php
$ echo nothing > nada.php
$ echo nothing > special.php

# Only --php
$ ag --php  -l hello .|cat
special_also.php
mmkay.php
blah.php

# Only --file-search-regex
$ ag  --file-search-regex special  -l hello .|cat
special_also.php
special_something.txt

# Both
$ ag --php --file-search-regex special  -l hello .|cat
special_also.php
mmkay.php
blah.php
```

Comment: Nice, not sure how I missed `-g` and `-G` back when I submitted my original answer. The OP's wording is kind of confusing but I think what he wants is to run a single command that searches all filenames as well as nonbinary file contents. Seems like `ag -g [search] && ag -l [search]` would work.

Comment: I suppose this is a better answer and I should mark this answer? Any thoughts?

Comment: @JikkuJose I added a new answer, which I believe solves your original question completely

Comment: @JikkuJose I think the community agrees that this is a better answer to your question.

Comment: `-g` also deserves a place in your answer.

Comment: Seems like correct answer, but does not work for me. ag does not seem to have a way to get version, so cannot know if it due to older version on brew/Mac.

Comment: @N0thing try `ag --version`

Comment: if you have extra time and are not in a rush, you can as well do it with our good old slower brother: `grep -Hirn --include "*haystack*" needle *`

Comment: chatgpt got me close, but humans still win for the moment... +1

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
find . | ag "/.*SEARCHTERM[^/]*$"
```

The command `find .` will list all files.

We pipe the output of that to the command `ag "/.*SEARCHTERM[^/]*$"`, which matches SEARCHTERM if it's in the filename, and not just the full path.

Comment: Had almost solved a variant using a simpler solution: ag -g . | ag 'search_term'; Yes, your pattern can be used to filter to the filename and not the path.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding this to your aliases file. Tested with zsh but should work with bash. The problem you encountered in your example is that bash aliases can't take parameters, so you have to first define a function to use the parameter(s) and then assign your alias to that function.

```
searchfunction() {
  echo $(ag -g $1 --hidden)
  echo $(ag --hidden -l $1)
}

alias search=searchfunction
```

You could modify this example to suit your purpose in a few ways, eg

- add/remove the `-l` flag depending on whether or not you want text results to show the text match or just the filename
- add headers to separate text results and filename results
- deduplicate results to account for files that match both on filename and text, etc.

[Edit: removed unnecessary --smart-case flag per Pablo Bianchi's comment]

Comment: Any way to tweak this to work with 'sack/sag' (https://github.com/sampson-chen/sack)? That would require combining the two ag queries into one so the search cache from first command that sack relies on wouldn't get blown away.

Comment: You can omit a parameter: `-S --smart-case` Match case-sensitively if there are any uppercase letters in PATTERN, case-insensitively otherwise. **Enabled by default.**

Comment: @PabloBianchi thanks. I had a (very) old version of ag, whose man page did not have the "enabled by default" note, but upon testing, it seems even old versions of ag did indeed use this flag by default. Updated my answer.

Comment: how to get this to output each result on a new line?

Answer (score 4):

Found this question looking for the same answer myself. It doesn't seem like `ag` has any native capability to search file and directory names. The answers above from Zach Fogg and Jikku Jose both work, but piping `find .` can be very slow if you're working in a big directory.

I'd recommend using `find` directly, which is much faster than piping it through `ag`:

Linux (GNU version of `find`)

```
find -name [pattern]
```

OSX (BSD version of `find`)

```
find [pattern]
```

If you need more help with `find`, [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-find-and-locate-to-search-for-files-on-a-linux-vps) from Digital Ocean is pretty good. I include this because the man pages for `find` are outrageously dense if you just want to figure out basic usage.

Comment: Thanks for confirming

Comment: @JikkuJose would you remove this as an accepted answer? Looking back, it is clearly incorrect in light of the `-g` and `-G` flags available with `ag`

Comment: @Greg fyi, `-g` is an output option

Answer (score 4):

To add to the previous answers, you can use an ["Or" Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986187/or-condition-in-regex) to search within files matching **different file extensions**.

For example to just search a string in C++ header files [**.hpp**] and Makefiles [**.mk**] ) :

`ag -G '.*\.(hpp|mk)' my_string_to_search`

Answer (score 1):

After being unsatisfied with `mdfind`, `find`, `locate`, and other attempts, the following worked for me. It uses `tree` to get the initial list of files, `ag` to filter out directories, and then `awk` to print the matching files themselves.

I wound up using `tree` because it was more (and more easily) configurable than the other solutions I tried and is fast.

This is a fish function:

```
function ff --description 'Find files matching given string'
  tree . --prune --matchdirs -P "*$argv*" -I "webpack" -i -f --ignore-case -p |
    ag '\[[^d].*' |
    awk '{print $2}'
end
```

This gives output similar to the following:

```
~/temp/hello_world $ ff controller
./app/controllers/application_controller.rb
./config/initializers/application_controller_renderer.rb
~/temp/hello_world $
```