# silver searcher fail for certain files

Tags: ag

I'm having trouble recently using [silver searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher).

There are 2 files in a directory containing same content:

---

**A.cpp:**

`This is a cpp file`

---

**B.cpp:**

`This is a cpp file`

---

However, `$ ag cpp` returns the result of `B.cpp`, not that of `A.cpp`:

> B.cpp
>
> 1:This is a cpp file

How do I deal with that?

*Here is the ag command [man page](https://www.mankier.com/1/ag)*

Comment: I installed silver search on my mac, created a directory and two files like you did, ran the same command and it listed both files correctly. Are you sure your file permissions are OK and you're searching the right directory and the files contain what you think they do?

Comment: Something to keep in mind is that this site isn't here to debug a 3rd party command like that. That would be something you'd want to take up with the open source project authors or maybe diagnose and fix the bug yourself.

Comment: You might found useful [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28056235/4970442).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `A.cpp` has been ignored.

Check your `.gitignore` and `.ignore`, etc..

Or you simply search all files with `$ ag cpp -u`.

See more detail by

`$ ag | ag "unrestricted"`

> -u --unrestricted       Search all files (ignore .ignore, .gitignore, etc.;
>                             searches binary and hidden files as well)