# Check input contains either pure numeric characters or pure alpha character using single regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have a function which will return true if input is pure numeric or alphabate else it will return false. This function is working fine.

```
function checktype($a)
{
    if (preg_match('/^\d+$/', $a)) { //check numeric (can use other numeric regex also like /^[0-9]+$/ etc)
        $return = true;
    } else if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+$/', $a)) { //check alphabates
        $return = true;
    } else { //others
        $return = false;
    }
    return $return;
}

var_dump(checktype('abcdfekjh')); //bool(true)
var_dump(checktype('1324654')); //bool(true)
var_dump(checktype('1324654hkjhkjh'));//bool(false)
```

No I tried to optimized this function by removing conditions so I modified code to:

```
function checktype($a)
{
    $return  = (preg_match('/^\d+$/', $a) || preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+$/', $a)) ? true:false;
    return $return;
}

var_dump(checktype('abcdfekjh')); //bool(true)
var_dump(checktype('1324654')); //bool(true)
var_dump(checktype('1324654hkjhkjh'));//bool(false)
```

Now in third step I tried to merge both regex in single regex so I can avoid two `preg_match` function and got stuck here:

```
function checktype($a)
{
    return (preg_match('regex to check either numeric or alphabates', $a)) ? true:false;
}
```

I tried a lot of combinations since 2 days by using `OR(!)` operator using `not operator(?!)` but no success at all.

Below some reference website from which i pick expression and made some combinations:

http://regexlib.com/UserPatterns.aspx?authorid=26c277f9-61b2-4bf5-bb70-106880138842

http://www.rexegg.com/regex-conditionals.html

[OR condition in Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986187/or-condition-in-regex)

[Regex not operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317043/regex-not-operator) (come to know about NOT operator)

https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=regular+expression+not+condition (come to know about NOT operator)

**So here main question is, is there any single regex pattern to check string contains pure numeric value or pure alphabates?**

> Note: Alternative solution can be check string is alphanumeric and then return `true` or `false` accordingly. Also php inbuilt function like `is_numeric` and `is_string` can be used, but I am more curious to know the single regex pattern to check weather string conains pure numeric digit or pure alphaba digits.

Comment: [`ctype_alpha()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php) and [`ctype_digit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php)

Comment: Even though `is_numeric` and `is_string` are comparatively faster than `preg_match`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A one regex to check if a string is all ASCII digits or all ASCII letters is

```
'/^(?:\d+|[a-zA-Z]+)$/'
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aT0oO5/2)

This regex has two things your regexps do not have:

- a grouping construct `(?:....)`
- an alternation operator `|`.

**Explanation**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\d+` - one or more digits
- `|`  - or...
- `[a-zA-Z]+)` - one or more ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string

If you need to make it Unicode-aware, use `[\p{L}\p{M}]` instead of `[a-zA-Z]` (and `\p{N}` instead of `\d`, but not necessary) and use the `/u` modifier:

```
'/^(?:\p{N}+|[\p{L}\p{M}]+)$/u'
```

And in case you want to really check that from the beginning to end, use

```
'/\A(?:\p{N}+|[\p{L}\p{M}]+)\z/u'
  ^^                        ^^
```

or

```
'/^(?:\p{N}+|[\p{L}\p{M}]+)$/Du'
```

The `$` without `/D` modifier does not match the string at its "very end", it also matches if there is a newline after it as the last character.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helps me a lot. This is exactly what i was looking for.